# Disposing of FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, filesystemwatcher

So my understanding is that whenever using a class that implements IDisposable, it's parent also needs to implement IDisposable interface. (FileWatcher using FileSystemWatcher)

So when using FileSystemWatcher what is the proper way of disposing of FileSystemWatcher? I want FileWatcher not to be disposed/(watching) until application is closed.

Would I use Responsible Owner Pattern?(try/finally) or something else?
Should my FileWatcher also implement IDisposable? I won't be able to use using{} since this fileWatcher should be watching the file changes the whole time application runs. What is the proper way of handling this scenario?

```
public class FileWatcher : IFileWatcher
{
    private FileSystemWatcher watcher;

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SettingsChanged;

    public FileWatcher(bool start)
    {
        this.RegisterForChanges();
    }

    public void OnChanged(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.SettingsChanged != null)
        {
            this.SettingsChanged(source, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void RegisterForChanges()
    {
        /// more code here etc
        ...
        this.watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
                           {
                               Path = directory, 
                               NotifyFilter =
                                   NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                   | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName, 
                               Filter = fileName
                           };

        // Add event handlers.
        this.watcher.Changed += this.OnChanged;

        // Begin watching.
        this.watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
```

Comment: `FileSystemWatcher` is pretty nasty to use -- very unreliable. You'll have a lot better of a time if you reuse an [existing wrapper](http://idcomlog.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#IdComLog.Reactive/FileSystem.cs) around it. The linked one uses Rx, but I'm sure you can find more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, implementing `IDisposable` is the right solution in this case (in my opinion). Your object is long-lived and has to live outside the scope of any particular function call so all function-scope level solutions (`using`, `try..finally`, etc.) are out.

For this, `IDisposable` is a standard pattern in .NET and you can easily dispose of the nested object when `FileWatcher` is disposed of.

Comment: Suppose my class FileWatcher is used in a windows service that runs continuously. It needs not to be disposed ever, or at least until a service is stopped or server crashes. I really can't use using{ } around all the global service code. Is this the right solution? Also, what's the point of calling Dispose() if that's the case (ie. service is stopped/ or server crashes-wouldn't the memory be cleared anyways?)

Comment: @ShaneKm When your service is stopped, it gets a notification from SCM and you can properly clean things up (by calling `Dispose` on the FSW). If your service crashes, you may not be able to clean up - the OS will attempt to clean up after the process and that likely includes the FSW but this should really be an exceptional scenario: you should guard your service code as much as possible to avoid crashes.

Comment: @ShaneKm And yes, your FSW _must_ be disposed when the service quits. It's not unusual for a service to run for a long time but when it stops, it still has to clean up after it. You'll have to manually call `Dispose` when this happens, from the shutdown code of the service - you cannot use `using`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

When shutting down an application, run the dispose method.

According to the method requested, when you want to dispose of something when your shutting down the program.

if you are using a class via, then IDisposable is for disposing the class object, but essentially you still might want to do it when you are shutting down the program

```
bool myFlag = false;
private FileSystemWatcher watcher;
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
           myFlag = true;
           if(myFlag)
           watcher.Dispose(); //Your FileSystemWatcher object
 }
```

Comment: The OP's pattern of wrapping the `FileSystemWatcher` in a class is much better because it encapsulates handling event listeners in one place.

Comment: Just instead of using it as a bear naked object call the instance of the class file and use the IDisposable method

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx