# FileSystemWatcher not running continiously

Tags: c#

Check the code bellow. I am following [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8) to build this function which will monitor file change infinite loop. But the problem i noticed is- Once these code run it tracks first 2-3 time file change after that this no longer continue to track the change. Note: i am not pressing `q` even tho somehow its stopping track the file change. Whats wrong i am doing here? How can i make it to run infinite loop and continue track the file change. Thanks in advance

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string location = textBox3.Text;
            if (location != "" & textBox1.Text != "" & textBox2.Text != "" & textBox3.Text != "" & textBox1.Enabled == false & textBox2.Enabled == false)
            {
                GlobalValues.Store = textBox1.Text;
                GlobalValues.Key = textBox2.Text;
                // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
                using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
                {
                    watcher.Path = location;
                    // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
                    // the renaming of files or directories.
                    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                         | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                         | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                         | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

                    // Only watch text files.
                    watcher.Filter = "*";
                    // Add event handlers.
                    watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
                    // Begin watching.
                    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    // Wait for the user to quit the program.
                    //Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit the sample.");
                    while (Console.Read() != 'q');

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would remove the using statement and that while loop and maybe keep a reference to that watcher at your app level so it doesn't get garbage collected. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508669/disposing-of-filesystemwatcher

Comment: @rene if i need to remove using then how to do this? Any example?

Comment: I assume you know how to delete `using(` and the `){` and a `}` as well as `while (Console.Read() != 'q');` . That doesn't need an example.

Comment: If i remove them then it wont track after first file change is made. so it is more worst now.

Comment: Move the `watcher` variable to the class level.

Comment: Wrong filter, should be `*.*` or `*.txt` for text files.  And any decent text editor never changes a file, that's far too dangerous with irrecoverable data loss when the disk burps.  They create a new file and rename it.  Subscribing the Error event is important.